# HTML/CSS coding problems

Tags: html, css

I have a header container on an HTML page:  and within that I have placed company's logo, background etc. The CSS for this is:

```
**#header {
        background-image:url(Images/background_top.png);**
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:270px;
    }
```

I have set the width to 100% as I would like it to fit any screen size.

The company's logo is added with an `img` (src,id) tag, then controlled in CSS.

I want to add a Facebook logo to the far right of this header, but every time I do it when i re-size the window the logo moves below the header and crashes into the rest of the page.

Can anyone help me please?

Here is the code:

```
All code: 

<div id="header">
    <img id="facebook_logo" src="Images/facebook_logo_extended.gif" />
    <img src="Images/logo.png" id="logo" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    background-image:url(Images/background_top.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:270px;
}

#logo {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:300px;  
    width:1000px;
    height:276px;
}

#facebook_logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    z-index:10;             
}
```

Now it floats right as i want it too but too far. now you have to scroll right to see it. When you do get to it a shrink the window size it runs into the main logo. Maybe im trying to get it to do something that cant happen!

Comment: Why havent you shown the facebook logo element as well?

Comment: Please add the full HTML which applies to this question.

Comment: Need to contain urge ... to indent ... code ....

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
#header{  background-image:url(Images/background_top.png);**
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:270px;
        }

#header img{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: All code: <div id="header">
<img id="facebook_logo" src="Images/facebook_logo_extended.gif" />
<img src="Images/logo.png" id="logo" />
</div>